# Angular 2 function for checking form input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm new to Angular.js 2 and i want to check a input value for age that if the value was lower than 18 it shows the danger text I tried this but it didn't work
can you give me a solution or correct the code?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'myForm',
    template:`
<div class="form-group">
        <label>age</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="age">
        <p class="text-danger" [style.display]="ageCheck(54) ? 'block' : 'none' ">You cannot register you're under 18!</p>
</div>
`
})

export class FormComponent {

ageCheck(age: number){
    if(age>=18) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `min`

```
        <label for="age">Age</label>

        <input type="number" min="18" class="form-control" required
          [(ngModel)]="model.age" name="age"  #age="ngModel" >

        <div [hidden]="age.valid || age.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          Age is required, should be 18+
        </div>
```

Note: user angular 2 RC3 for `#age="ngModel"` to work

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use ng-show or ng-if  in that case instead of playing directly with the style. This would look like (not tested):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>age</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="age">
    <p class="text-danger" ng-show="age>18">{{age}}</P
    <p class="text-danger" ng-show="age<=18">You cannot register you're under 18!</p>
</div>
```

That would do exactly what you ask above. Since this looks more like a validation you can create your validator to be more inline with angular philosophy by implementind a directive in your module.

```
myModule.directive('ageCheck', function() {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope,element,attributes,ngModel) {
            ngModel.$validators.ageCheck=function(modelValue) {
                return scope.age>18;
            }
        }
    }
});

<form name="action">
<div class="form-group">
<label>age</label>
<input type="number" name="ageField" class="form-control" ng-model="age" age-check>
<p class="text-danger" ng-show="action.ageField.$error.ageCheck">You cannot register you're under 18!</p>
</div>
```

If you are new to Angular I strongly suggest to go through their official tutorial which is much better then others I did before. It really brings help me understand the injector/module/minification. You should also start your project using the [seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

Comment: This is to inform you that this question belongs to Angular2. You have come up with Angular1 solution.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `ageCheck` function,

this should work I guess,

```
<p class="text-danger" [style.display]="age<=18 && age!=undefined ? 'block' : 'none' ">You cannot register you're under 18!</p>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/aKqBBly2zlT3pijmnwEM?p=preview

OR

```
<p class="text-danger" [style.display]="ageCheck(age) ? 'block' : 'none' ">You cannot register you're under 18!</p>

ageCheck(age: number){ 

    if(age<=18 && age!=undefined) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: actually as i said I'm new to angular and I want to practice using function , is there any way to use the function?

Comment: Check my link and answer. With and without a function.